# Running a 220 V dust collector with 24 V switches

Tags: voltage, transformer, switches

I have a 5 hp, 220 V, 30 A dust collector that I want to turn on and off with 24 V switches attached to my blast gates. Can I simply use a 220 V to 24 V transformer?

Comment: Relay sounds like a better option (without knowing more details).

Comment: For better understanding about the topic, I'll check the website out. I'm sure it has more details and illustrations for a better explanation of the subject.

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to get some properly sized and UL approved components to perform this function.

Go to an HVAC supply store in your area and purchase a properly rated "contactor", a 24 VAC transformer and a UL-approved metal enclosure to house the contactor. You'll also need an assortment of cable clamp accessories which you can get at a Home Depot or Lowes.

A "contactor" is a large relay which is specifically designed to control motors and other heavy loads. They come in a variety of sizes and contact ratings, as well as coil voltages. 24-28 VAC coils are very common. This is the coil you will need to use your "24 Volt Switches".

The contactor you need is either a SPST or a SPDT, although you might have to choose a DPST or DPDT as these are more commonly available. You need one with a contact rating of 30 amps or more. Often contactors are rated according to the motor horsepower they can reliably switch.

Make sure to get the metal enclosure and use it in your installation. Contactors by their nature have a lot of exposed metal which is at the line voltage, so you'll want to make sure this is all properly enclosed to prevent accidental contact with human body parts.

Dust collectors have a number of explosive hazards. You'll want to read up on properly locating your contactor so that it's sparks (yes, the contacts will spark some when they are opened and closed) so you don't create a hazard. One of the other posters suggested some sites where you can find such information.

Good Luck!

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you go to Lumberjocks (http://www.lumberjocks.com) where you will find many woodworkers with experience controlling dust collectors.  Search their forums for discussion on the topic, and the projects and blogs - I recall seeing descriptions of dust collection systems there...

For a 5 hp motor, you will certainly need a proper motor starter (contactor) which can be controlled by 24 V.  A 240/24 or 120/24 volt transformer would be used to power the control circuit.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see how stepping the voltage down to 24V will allow you to control it. Once you step it down, you are basically switching to output of the device used to switch down the voltage. It will not allow you to control input device.

Relays are preferred in this situation.

Here is a good circuit:

[image]

The low current trigger could be your switch. You might need an extra 12V/9V battery to use in series with the switch and the relay (also connect a resistor.) The high current circuit would be your dust collector.  The relay will behave as a switch for that circuit.

Comment: What do you mean by __"You might need an extra 12V/9V battery to use in series with the switch and the relay(also connect a resistor)."__ ? If the problem is controlling a big 220v load from a 24v source, use a relay with a 24v coil and contacts rated for the 220v load.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely a relay solution.  The circuit is just as Sherby posted above.  One small sizing detail is not included though.  The contacts of a relay have two ratings important for this application.  The amp rating generally advertised is typically the full working load rating which is the number of amps drawn while the motor is running.  However on startup the motor will draw significantly more amps in the order of 5 to 10 times the number of amps it draws while running.  Starts from a complete stop take more energy/current until the motor is up to speed. It generally does this for a short period of time. The amps that represent this inrush of current are what I believe the resistive amps rating of the relay represents.  You can find that specification in the specification detail for the relay.

So in my case while my motor is rated at 14 amps, during a run it only draws 8 amps.  On startup however it draws 56 to 57 amps for a short time.  These numbers were indicated with all blast gates closed....the worst case situation.  This inrush will burn out the contacts on a relay not rated for that amount either immediately or over time.  My long way of saying that you should measure your units amps during run and startup and use those numbers to size the values of the contactor relay (Running amps and resistive amps).  For my 1.5HP 120VAC dust collector I bought a one pole 40AMP relay with a resistive load rating of 50AMPS.  Not sure how it will do but I suspect it is close enough because I believe my startup amps will decrease if the motor starts with at least one blast gate open.